# Long time running javascript in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

After a long time running script in Firefox(several hours), the browser behaves as follows:
[image: two muppets]
The icon spins all the time, new tabs cannot be opened. In this case, the script continues to work.
The script runs cyclically.

Tell me: maybe I need to somehow clear the memory or cache or something else?
version of Firefox 63.0.3(64-bit)

Comment: perhaps you need check memory usage of firefox - looks like memory issue to me, probably due to poorly written javascript

Answer (score 0):

Any long-running script that runs directly in the web page will cause that page to freeze up, even though the script is still running. If you need a script to be running in the background *without* freezing up the page, take a look at [web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers)